# AWS Eventbridge Filter ECS Cluster Deployment with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to build a simple Eventbridge -> SNS -> AWS Chatbot to notify Slack channel for any ECS deployment events. Below are my codes

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "ecs_deployment" {
  name = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-infra-ecs-deployment"
  description = "This rule sends notification on the all app ECS Fargate deployments with respect to the environment."

  event_pattern = <<EOF
{
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail-type": ["ECS Deployment State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "clusterArn": [
      {
        "prefix": "arn:aws:ecs:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:cluster/${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-"
      }
    ]
  }
}
EOF

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Origin      = "terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "ecs_deployment" {
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.ecs_deployment.name
  target_id = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-infra-ecs-deployment"
  arn = aws_sns_topic.ecs_deployment.arn
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "ecs_deployment" {
  name = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-infra-ecs-deployment"
  display_name = "${var.namespace} ${var.environment}"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.ecs_deployment.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_topic_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_topic_policy" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["SNS:Publish"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    resources = [aws_sns_topic.ecs_deployment.arn]
  }
}
```

Based on the above code, Terraform will create AWS Eventbridge rule and with SNS target. From there, I create AWS Chatbot in the console, and subscribe to the SNS.

The problem is, when I try to remove the detail, it works. But what I want is to filter the events to be coming from cluster with mentioned prefix.

Is this possible? Or did I do it the wrong way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the AWS docs, I don't see this way of representing the cluster ARN:     `"clusterArn": [{ "prefix": "arn:aws:ecs:<REGION>:ACCOUNT>:cluster/${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-"}]`. As I understand it, it's only a single string, i.e., `"clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:<REGION>:ACCOUNT>:cluster/${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-<rest of the name>"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MarkoE I also suspect it was because of that. So in other words, currently there is no possible way to filter the event based on some prefixes?

Just a note, if you're using console, and try to create an ECS event there, you would find that you can filter for clusters by using list [] but those in console are only ECS events other than `ECS Deployment State Change`.